# Find substring with certain pattern anywhere in a string

Tags: string, matlab, find

I got many strings from our device (array). There are two different kinds of strings :

1. *011_c_srr_Rtzfi_at000_hh5_fs_v343_**l067**_i1_Test_Test*
2. *041_c_ddr_Rtzfi_ds000_hh5_fs_v343_**l037**_i1_Test_hall*  (the needed information is in the middle of the string)
3. *061_t_err_Rsas_au000_ti3_fs_v777_**l011**_* *
4. *021_t_err_Rsas_au230_ti3_fs_v777_**l031**_* (the needed information is at the end of the string)

Conclusion: I need the following part of the string  **l067 / l037 /  l011** ..... For example **l067** means 67% and I037 means 37%. So i need this two percent values. The result is **67** and **37**.
My Code: (only parts)

```
for j=1:numRows;
Name=LaSP.Messung(j, 1).name
Size=size(Name)
Length = strlength(Name)%Evaluiert die Länge des gesamten Strings
pos1 = findstr(Name, '_')%Listet alle "_" im String auf
[zeile1,spalte1]=size(pos1)
spalte=pos1(1,spalte1)%ich hol mir string position vom letzten "_"

if spalte==Length%Abfrage ob das letzte zeichen ist ein "_"
%%Abfrage ob der Wert schon einmal vorkam   
    %%die letzten 4 auslesen
else 
    %%in mitten des strings
end

      %pos = strfind(Name, '_')
 %k = strfind(Name,'_','ForceCellOutput',true)
 %idx = find(strcmp(Name, '_'))
 %pat='_';
%ind=regexp(Name,pat);
% word_to_find=strfind(strarray,'stringtofind');
% starray.index(word_to_find);
end
```

My problem is i can not split the string ... i can not extract the last 4 characters...
Thank you

Comment: You may want to give a go to regular expressions

Comment: Thanks for posting your desired input & output and code, but what is the problem with the code? Were are you stuck?  (Sidenote: whilst not disallowed on SO, having your in-code comments in German makes it more difficult to understand for non-German speakers). I'd do a `strplit()` on the dash, `_`, and then grab the ninth cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
my_strings = {'011_c_srr_Rtzfi_at000_hh5_fs_v343_l067_i1_Test_Test',
'041_c_ddr_Rtzfi_ds000_hh5_fs_v343_l037_i1_Test_hall',
'061_t_err_Rsas_au000_ti3_fs_v777_l011_ *',
'021_t_err_Rsas_au230_ti3_fs_v777_l031_'};
```

few possible solutions here.

1. Using [regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to match, we can build our pattern to look for the characters after `v` followed by three digits and underscore (e.g. `v777_`)

   ```
   matches = regexp(my_strings,'v\d{3}_([^_]+)','tokens','once');
   [matches{:}]
   ans =

     1×4 cell array

     {'l067'}    {'l037'}    {'l011'}    {'l031'}
   ```
2. Using [regex](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to split on underscore, and then taking the 9th cell:

   ```
   split_strings = regexp(my_strings,'_','split');
   matches = cellfun(@(x) x(9),split_strings).'
   ans =

    1×4 cell array

    {'l067'}    {'l037'}    {'l011'}    {'l031'}
   ```
3. Using [strsplit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) to split on underscore, and then taking the 9th cell:

   ```
   n = numel(my_strings);
   matches = char.empty(0,n);
   for i = 1:n
     split_string = strsplit(my_strings{i},'_');
     matches = [matches split_string(9)];
   end
   matches =

     1×4 cell array

     {'l067'}    {'l037'}    {'l011'}    {'l031'}
   ```

Comment: Hello one question again... What shall i do if it is not the 9th cell?

Comment: @FranzH Which cell is it? Just `9` to that number